# How to derive cutoff frequency equations from the transfer function

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am working on a problem from the textbook Electric Circuits 10th edition

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fosoZX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to figure out first how to go from the transfer function to the magnitude. It's almost as if the denominator gets a \$ w^2 \$ out of nowhere. Then, I can't seem to figure out how to move from the magnitude in order to solve for the cutoff frequencies.

\$ H(s)=\frac{\frac{R}{L}\times s}{s^2+(\frac{R+R_i}{L})s+\frac{1}{LC}} \$ - using voltage divider

\$ |H(jw)|=\frac{\frac{R}{L}w}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{LC}-w^2)^2+(w\frac{R+R_1}{L})^2}}\$

We can find the cutoff frequencies:

\$\frac{R}{R_1+R}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2)}}) = \frac{\frac{R}{L}w}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{LC}-w^2)^2+(w\frac{R+R_1}{L})^2}}\$

The cutoff frequencies are then defined as:

\$wc_1 = -\frac{R+R_1}{2L}+\sqrt{(\frac{R+R_1}{2L})^2+\frac{1}{LC}}\$

\$wc_2 = \frac{R+R_1}{2L}+\sqrt{(\frac{R+R_1}{2L})^2+\frac{1}{LC}}\$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{180}{180+20+40\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\text{s}+\frac{1}{40\cdot10^{-9}\cdot\text{s}}}=$$
$$\frac{4500\cdot\text{s}}{625000000+\text{s}\cdot\left(5000+\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

Now, for sinuscoidal signals we can write:

$$\text{s}=\omega\text{j}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\mathcal{H}\left(\omega\text{j}\right)\right|=\frac{4500\cdot\omega}{\sqrt{\left(625000000-\omega^2\right)^2+\left(5000\cdot\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

And the maximum is given at:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\hat{\omega}}\left(\frac{4500\cdot\hat{\omega}}{\sqrt{\left(625000000-\hat{\omega}^2\right)^2+\left(5000\cdot\hat{\omega}\right)^2}}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=25000\tag4$$

By the definition of the cutoff frequency we have to find:

$$\frac{4500\cdot\omega}{\sqrt{\left(625000000-\omega^2\right)^2+\left(5000\cdot\omega\right)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\mathcal{H}\left(\hat{\omega}\text{j}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\omega=2500\cdot\left(\sqrt{101}\pm1\right)\tag5$$

Comment: How did you get \$w^2\$ in the denominator for step 3?

Comment: @ArthurGreen Try to expand the factor \$500000000+\text{s}(4000+\text{s})\$ from equation \$(1)\$

Comment: I put your cutoff $$\omega=400\cdot\sqrt{3156\pm\sqrt{19711}}\tag4$$ into the calculator and got 21.965k and 22.965k

The textbook solution is 22.625k and 27.625k https://imgur.com/a/05ojdoz

I will try and go through the math again

Comment: @ArthurGreen I verified mine using Mathematica.

Comment: Did you get the same values I did?

Comment: @ArthurGreen No, I got the values that are stated in my answer.

Comment: The values in your answer are the same. I plugged your step 4 into wolfram to find the exact value so I may compare with the solution in my book.

Comment: $$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{180}{180+20+40\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\text{s}+\frac{1}{40\cdot10^{-9}\cdot\text{s}}}= \frac{4500 \times s}{s^2+5000 \times s+625000000}$$

Comment: @ArthurGreen Sorry I made an error my Mathematica code. I fixed it

Comment: There is one more step I see I cannot edit your post yet, but we need to set step 4 = \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \times \frac{R}{R_1+R}\$ I get the same answers as solution with this added. What program do you use to write your LaTeX? It's really clean. Is mathematica wolfram?

Comment: @ArthurGreen Personally (I'm not Jan), I just write the Latex code. The site does all the preparation and handling before spitting out the web page. I think you can start looking [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax?) for some discussions about using MathJax's version of Latex for this site.

Comment: @ArthurGreen I figured out why to have to do the step with the resistors times one of the squareroot of 2. If you want to know it, let me know and I'll explain!

Comment: @Jan Yes, I'd love to hear why. I spent five hours deep learning this stuff yesterday I am hungry for information.

Comment: @ArthurGreen I'll edit my answer later tonight (here in The Netherlands it is almost night) so that you can learn how to deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: @ArthurGreen See my edit!